# How to get a list of all structs where struct.somearray contains an element from a query array

Tags: matlab

As input to a function, I am getting an array of target elements, `T`, and an array of structs `S` where each one has a `.elems` field, which is a list of integers (elements).

I'm sure there's a simple way to do this in Matlab.  How do I get the indices `i` of all structs where a specific element `t` of `T` is in `S(i).elems` contains `t`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think you'll need to do this with an arrayfun. I did:

```
S = ... (1-by-N array of structs);
T = ... (1-by-K array of numbers);
indices = find(arrayfun(@(i)any(ismember(T, S(i).elems)), 1:numel(S)));
```

`any(ismember(T, S(i)elems))` tests is any of the things in T are in S(i).elems. The `arrayfun` repeats this for each struct in S. `find` extracts indices from the logical array that is returned by the arrayfun.